# Can't access a plain html/css/php page on server that is currently hosting a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, server

I need some help with a problem I'm facing.

I need to access a plain html/css/php page on server that is currently hosting a wordpress site

So I have a client, my 1st one. And the task was to create a hotspot login page to be uploaded to their current website. The page is made and is working perfectly in localhost. You can see it [here](http://bhaviljain.000webhostapp.com).

But the problem is with the server and its directory setup.

He has 2 websites running, 1st one is non wordpress and the 2nd one is running on wordpress. (as far as i can say, looking a the files in the root directory and the subdirectory).

So the Directory structure is ROOT/website1_files/website2_files/Hotspot/portal.php
(I hope that's understandable, website1 files are in the root directory)

From my browser when I try to access www.website2.com/Hotspot/portal.php I get Error 404 page not found. 
I searched stackoverflow/youtube and other places

Most solutions were to edit the .htaccess file on the server. 
Any change I made to htaccess led to HTTP 500 error.

The Things I've tired

1. set RewriteEngine to off in website2's htaccess
2. 1st one + creating a new htaccess file in the hotspot folder and defining the directory index as portal.php
3. set RewriteEngine to off in website1's htaccess.
4. Completely deleting the htaccess files in website2 and hotspot folder.
5. Put Hotspot folder in the root.

None of these have worked.

please..If some one can help .. it would be great!!

This is my very 1st client, so it would lead to a very bad start of my upwork profile if i cant deliver :( :(

website2 .htaccess (Original)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

website2 .htaccess (edited)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(Hotspot|Hotspot/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Hotspot folder .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex portal.php
```

Website1 .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^moonshinedistillers\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.moonshinedistillers\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/moonshinedistiller\.com\/" [R=301,L]


# Never use www in the domain
# Replace 'example.com' with your domain name
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# SEO URL Settings
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.moonshinedistiller\.com
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.moonshinedistiller.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [F] 


Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>


<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

# Caching set to 1 month for images
<Files *.jpg>
Header add "Cache-Control" "max-age=2629000"
</Files>
<Files *.png>
Header add "Cache-Control" "max-age=2629000"
</Files>
<Files *.gif>
Header add "Cache-Control" "max-age=2629000"
</Files>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from 97.122.203.221

#<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
#ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
#ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
#ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
#ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
#ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
#ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
#ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
#ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 year"
# Javascript
#ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
#</IfModule>


#Redirect 301 /index.php https://moonshinedistiller.com
#Redirect 301 /index.htm https://moonshinedistiller.com
#Redirect 301 /index.html https://moonshinedistiller.com
#Redirect 301 /index.shtml https://moonshinedistiller.com
#Redirect 301 /index.asp https://moonshinedistiller.com
#Redirect 301 /default.asp https://moonshinedistiller.com
#Redirect 301 /default.aspx https://moonshinedistiller.com
#Redirect 301 /index.aspx https://moonshinedistiller.com
#Redirect 301 /index.cfm https://moonshinedistiller.com
#Redirect 301 /index.pl https://moonshinedistiller.com
#Redirect 301 /default.htm https://moonshinedistiller.com

Redirect 301 /24-inch-2-inch-column-extender  https://moonshinedistiller.com/column-tower-extender-12-inches?filter_name=column%2520extender
Redirect 301 /whiskey-distillers-yeast-turbo-72-grams  https://moonshinedistiller.com/moonshine-distiller-whiskey-distillers-yeast?filter_name=whiskey
Redirect 301 /top-shelf-french-brandy https://moonshinedistiller.com/french-brandy-essence-top-shelf?filter_name=french%2520brandy
Redirect 301 /bulk-turbo-yeast-10-kilograms  https://moonshinedistiller.com/moonshine-turbopure-yeast?filter_name=turbo
Redirect 301 /turbo-yeast-power https://moonshinedistiller.com/24-hour-turbo-yeast?filter_name=turbo%2520yeast%2520power
Redirect 301 /top-shelf-rye-whiskey-essence https://moonshinedistiller.com/rye-whiskey-essence?filter_name=apricot%2520bransy%2520essence
Redirect 301 /top-shelf-scotch-whiskey https://moonshinedistiller.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=scotch
Redirect 301 /vodka-distillers-yeast-turbo-72-grams  https://moonshinedistiller.com/vodka-pure-yeast-liquor-quik?filter_name=vodka%2520disttillers%2520yeast
Redirect 301 /48-hour-turbo-yeast-140-grams https://moonshinedistiller.com/48-hour-turbo-yeast?filter_name=48%2520hour%2520turbo%2520yeast
Redirect 301 /top-shelf-irish-cream  https://moonshinedistiller.com/irish-cream-liqueur-essence?filter_name=irish%2520cream%5c
Redirect 301 /12-gallon-plastic-fermenter-bucket  https://moonshinedistiller.com/6-gallon-plastic-fermenter-bucket?filter_name=12%2520gallon%2520frementer%2520bucket
Redirect 301 /turbo-500-still-t500-system  https://moonshinedistiller.com/turbo-500-still-T500-system?filter_name=turbo%2520500
Redirect 301 /vodka-distillers-yeast-turbo-72-grams?filter…  https://moonshinedistiller.com/vodka-pure-yeast-liquor-quik?filter_name=vodka%2520distillers%2520yeaast%2520turbo
Redirect 301 /top-shelf-hazelnut-liqueur-kit-still-spirits  https://moonshinedistiller.com/index.php?route=product/product&filter_name=still+spirits&product_id=322
Redirect 301 /13-gallon-milk-can-distilling-boiler-stainle… https://moonshinedistiller.com/13-gallon-milk-can-distilling-boiler-stainless-steel-3-inch?filter_name=milk%2520can%2520distiller&page=2
Redirect 301 /moonshine-distiller-still-13-gallon  https://moonshinedistiller.com/moonshine-kit-13-gallon?filter_name=distiller%2520still%252013%2520gallon&page=1
Redirect 301 /top-shelf-irish-whiskey-essence  https://moonshinedistiller.com/irish-whiskey-essence?filter_name=irish%2520whiskey
Redirect 301 /top-shelf-absinthe-essence  https://moonshinedistiller.com/absinthe-essence?filter_name=absinthe%2520essence&page=1
Redirect 301 /top-shelf-bourbon  https://moonshinedistiller.com/bourbon-essence?filter_name=bourbon
Redirect 301 /copper-tri-clover-ferrule-for-homemade-moons… https://moonshinedistiller.com/copper-tri-clover-ferrule-for-homemade-moonshine-still?filter_name=tri%2520clover%2520ferrule
Redirect 301 /copper-tri-clover  https://moonshinedistiller.com/copper-tri-clover-ferrule-3-inch-sanitary-fitting?filter_name=copper%2520tri%2520clover

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With"
```

Comment: We cannot help you without a bit of code, share us the htaccess code you've tried  - only then we can help.

Comment: @Soaku : Code added. This is how the code looks after I've edited it

Comment: Aren't you rewriting to index.php, while you're using portal.php? By the way, Rewrite* commands require RewriteEngine to be on.

Comment: First off, leave the original .htaccess files the way they were. If you change anything related to these files and apache, you have to restart apache, so all your experimentation is a waste of time. The htaccess files you have listed would break wordpress and their existing site.
Please update your question with original working website2 .htaccess.

Comment: @Soaku : I'm trying to access a file which is portal.php.
Its under website2/hotspot/portal.php.

Comment: @gview : Added the original htaccess file from website2

Comment: @BhavilJain Then your 404 error comes from rewriting to /index.php which doesn't exist. Replace index.php with portal.php in your htaccess

Comment: @Soaku but wouldn't that break wordpress?? Coz the server needs to access the index.php of wordpress. This was the primary reason i kept the fil name as portal .php, to avoid confusion

Also, in which .htaccess file are you asking me to make the change?

Comment: You want user to access portal.php or index.php then? I don't get what you want to do. I don't know what WP does, because I never used that.

Comment: @Soaku : Lol.. same here, hate WP, It just complicates things. As for your question. I want people to access the file/page that is named portal.php. Now naming it portal.php or index.php is not a matter.